# Do I need a higher level tool to implant?

Tags: neocron

I currently have a TL30 Remote Implant Tool which I use for implanting other people, I have noticed that I can poke implants higher than TL30 with this tool on other people, but when I am using a Personal Implant Tool I need to have a tool with an equal or higher level than the implant I am trying to poke in order to succeed.

Am I able to poke all implants of any tech level with a TL30 Remote Implant Tool or will I need to get a TL150 tool in order to implant tech level 115 implants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't, a TL30 remote implant tool is sufficient for all remote implanting regardless of the TL of the implant you're poking in - all that is required is your implant ability, so to implant a TL115 implant you can use a TL30 remote implant tool with 115 points in the implant ability.